# how to add white space into conditional regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have the following data annotation for one of my properties:

```
[RegularExpression(@"A|B|C|A and B", ErrorMessage = "You must select one.")]
```

When I submit the value "A and B" it does not accept this, but if i post "A", "B", or "C" it passes.  How would i make it so the full string "A and B" will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "A and B" in parentheses:

```
[RegularExpression(@"A|B|C|(A and B)", ErrorMessage = "You must select one.")]
```